# Changed the WCF service from http to https when SSL is on service not working

Tags: .net, wcf, https

We are trying to change the url from Http to HTTPS after adding below details also url is not working.

Please suggest on how to proceed furtur on changing http to https

/* behavior starts  */

```
        <serviceBehaviors>

            <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">

                <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="3" maxConcurrentInstances="3" maxConcurrentSessions="3"/>

                <serviceTimeouts transactionTimeout="00:10:00"/>

                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
            
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>

                <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress/>

            </behavior>

        </serviceBehaviors>

    </behaviors>
```

/* behavior ends */

/* This is the place where binding tag starts */

```
    <bindings>
        
        <basicHttpsBinding>

            <binding name="httpsBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">

                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>

            </binding>

        </basicHttpsBinding>

    </bindings>
```

/* binding ends */

Comment: Can you provide some more detailed error logs? If you are using IIS to host the service, you also need to change the Settings. In addition, basicHttpsBinding is a feature provided by wcf 4.5. Please check the version or set it to basicHttpBinding and change the security mode to transport. See [the link](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/631886/Change-IIS-binding-from-http-to-https) for more details.